# iterm vim colorscheme not working

Tags: macos, vim, iterm

When I run vim from the command line in iTerm, syntax highlighting doesn't seem to work locally.

In vim for example I have installed a nice colorscheme that works quite well in MacVim but it would be great if in iTerm it showed the same one.

Any ideas how I can turn this on?

This is the color scheme I'm trying to use
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2340

Answer (score 80, accepted):

That color scheme looks like it only supports 256-color terminals.  If Vim thinks that your terminal only supports 8 colors, you won't see that specific color scheme.

You can check this in Vim by:

```
:echo &t_Co
```

If that returns `8`, this might be the problem.  Try setting it to 256 in your `~/.vimrc` and see if that helps:

```
let &t_Co=256
```

Comment: I would presume that there must be some setting in iTerm, to allow 256 colours?

Comment: Doesn't work for me under the 10.6 default terminal. It causes the text vim to flash black and white.

Comment: Apparently the mac terminal only supports 16 colors, http://jimlund.org/blog/?p=130.

Comment: New versions of iTerm2 now correctly set TERM=xterm-256color, so vim should know the correct number of colours are supported without setting any variables if you have a recent enough version. Otherwise, you can set this value in iTerm's preferences under the 'Terminal' tab.

Comment: The ":echo &t_Co" command doesn't return anything for me. (iTerm on Snow Leopard)

Comment: wow thank you so much, this has bothered me for YEARS and I never bothered trying to fix it.

Comment: Not "8 colors", 8-bit colors. Meaning 256 colors. Just pointing that out, haha

Comment: Hmmm. I have the latest version of iTerm2. The `echo &t_Co` reports 256. I still don't get the same syntax highlighting that MacVim gets automatically.

Answer (score 85):

In order to turn code highlighting on in vim, try to enable the syntax plugin:

```
:syntax enable
```

Comment: On a side note, many of the schemes are made for GVim / MacVim and don't necessarily display to their entirety inside the terminal.

Comment: Add "syntax on" without quotes to .vimrc file to make it permanent

Answer (score 29):

To those who still have problem.

iTerm 2 -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Colors -> Minimum contrast -> lowest

[image: setup]

Comment: For me, I changed the `Color Presets` then it works.

Comment: I wonder why the default is set so high?  I thought I was losing my mind.

Answer (score 13):

I've had this problem before, as well as some related issues, so I'll summarize what I found.

1. Make sure iTerm is set to use 256 colors. Try `$ echo $TERM`at the command line, and if you don't see `xterm-256color` then follow the directions [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7427618/276457).
2. Set up your `vimrc` to handle other terminals as well. The  regular Terminal in Snow Leopard only supports 8 colors for instance and will blink if you try to use a 256 color color scheme (I just don't set one in that case).  Here's what I have:

   ```
   " enable 256 colors in GNOME terminal (for my Ubuntu VM)
   if $COLORTERM == 'gnome-terminal'
       set t_Co=256
   endif

   " set your color scheme (replace wombat with whatever yours is called)
   " if you're using a gvim or macvim, then your color scheme may have a version
   " that uses more than 256 colors
   if has("gui_running")
       colorscheme wombat
   elseif &t_Co == 256
       colorscheme wombat256
   endif

   " turn on language specific syntax highlighting
   syntax on
   ```

Answer (score 5):

After trying all the other answers here, the final thing I needed was:

```
set termguicolors
```

Answer (score 4):

Despite following all the advice in this (and other, similar) questions, I eventually found my trouble in a forgotten part of a vimrc I had taken from somewhere on the web years ago (because it was rather nicely organised), and then extensively modified for my own purposes.

But the problem area was in a little group of settings that I had never touched, back in the original file I started with.  The relevant bit of the .vimrc was:

```
   " GVIM- (here instead of .gvimrc)
   if has('gui_running')
          set guioptions-=T               " remove the toolbar
          set lines=40                    " 40 lines of text instead of 24,
   else
           set term=builtin_ansi       " Make arrow and other keys work
   endif
```

Unsurprisingly (in retrospect), that "set term" line resets things so that regardless of what type your terminal is reporting in the TERM environment variable, you wind up with a generic, 8-color ANSI terminal.  Setting 'term' explicitly inside the .vimrc is probably a very bad idea, just like setting t_Co directly.

I removed this whole block (And put the gvim settings into .gvimrc, where they belong), and everything has been working correctly for me ever since.

Answer (score 3):

Edit sudo vim ~/.vimrc and add "syntax on" should fix issue.

Comment: You don't need `sudo` here, just `vim ~/.vimrc` will do.