# vim colorschemes not changing background color

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I try to apply various color schemes in vim that I have seen on the net. Whatever scheme I choose, the background remains white, even though screenshots of the applied scheme shows that the background should be colored.

In some schemes, some of the background change color, but space right of lines containing text still remains white.

I'm using Vim 7.2 on a mac. I have just started messing with non-gui applications, so everything should be pretty much as it was out of the box..

Does the overall settings for the terminal window have something to do with it?

When running macvim, everything looks ok. Its only when starting vim from the terminal things looks strange..

Answer (score 49):

I have this in my .vimrc and it solved this problem for me using while using PuTTY.

```
set t_Co=256
set background=dark
colorscheme mustang
highlight Normal ctermbg=NONE
highlight nonText ctermbg=NONE
```

It's important to load the colorscheme before the ctermbg settings in .vimrc because they need to override the same ones set by the colorscheme. This also means you can't switch colorscheme while Vim is running and expect it to work.

Comment: I use `monokai.vim` and the first two lines were already in the `monokai.vim` file, so the last two - `highlight` - lines where the important part.  I did not need to set `t_Co` and `background` twice.  Thanks!

Comment: Yay! First thing on this page I tried that actually worked.

Comment: only needed set t_CO=256 for my colorschemes to work properly

Answer (score 30):

I'm adding a second answer from me because it's very different from my first answer and may point to actual problem.

If you look at the actual website for the colorscheme here:
[Molokai website](http://winterdom.com/2008/08/molokaiforvim)

you will see a question very similar to yours.  Here's answer given, which suggests trying command `:set t_Co=256` in your vimrc to see if it fixes things:

"- Make sure you’re using a console terminal capable of 256 colors; not all of them do (particularly on mac). You might need to explicitly force Vim to use that by doing “set t_Co=256″ on your .vimrc file.
- The windows console is well… totally unsupported, that only does 16 colors so it’s a mess"

Comment: I'm putty'ing into my mac (10.6), with zsh and vim. `:set t_Co=256` just brightened up my world.

Comment: This solved my problem running vim(not gvim) from Gnome Terminal. I can now load my monokai theme I downloaded and actually see the color change!

Comment: Also, better verify that `echo $TERM` in bash has value `xterm-256color`. If its value is `xterm`, even manually doing `:set t_Co=256` in vim will give less beautiful colors. (Normally, vim will do `:set t_Co=256` for you when it see $TERM environment variable having value `xterm-256color`)

Answer (score 14):

In linux I had `export TERM=xterm-256color` in my `.bashrc`. That caused vim to look like this (after setting `set t_Co=256`):

[image: Vim looks with molokai theme before fixing TERM variable]

When I removed that line from my `.bashrc` and opened a new terminal (`exec bash` didn't do it) This is what I get:

[image: Vim looks with molokai theme after fixing TERM variable]

Comment: You saved my life :-) I was connecting on a Debian machine over ssh from my Mac and I had the exact same problem as in your screenshot. This was the solution for my vim to start working.

Answer (score 8):

Terminals are usually limited to 256 colors while GUI are only limited by color depth of your desktop environment, typically 2^32.

So even if there is lots of vim color scheme available around, implicitly they are often designed for the GUI and won't work for the terminal version.

If you look at color schemes on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=&script_type=color+scheme&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search), there is often a mention of GUI or 256. So you have to chose which to use depending on the context.

To convert a GUI scheme to terminal you can use the following plugin :
[CSApprox](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390).

You can also use a different colorscheme depending on the context, add the following in your .vimrc:

```
if has("gui_running")  
    colorscheme [using any color you want]  
else  
    colorscheme [using 256 colors]  
endif
```

Comment: So, how can I know the teams that I try out get limited because of color restrictions?

Comment: Molokai colorscheme (http://bit.ly/fRSH4F) claims support for 256 colors, but the background still remains white...

Comment: There might be an answer there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761770/iterm-vim-colorscheme-not-working which is mentioning iTerm and 256 colors support.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem could be the way the default color is changed by the colorscheme.  I've looked at some colorschemes that set default merely by:

```
set background=light
```

or

```
set background=dark
```

Not sure what limitations of those are.  I don't think those work in terminals.

In any case, you should be able to manually set background in a terminal by using the 'Normal' highlight.  Insert it into a spot before most of the 'hi' commands in the colorscheme file and it should provide defaults they will work with.   For example:

```
hi Normal ctermbg=White ctermfg=Black guifg=Black guibg=White
```

Change ctermfg (color terminal foreground) and ctermbg (color terminal background) to be whatever you want (or whatever color you were expecting to see in the colorscheme but now aren't seeing).  (Remember, though, if the colorscheme already has a setting for hi Normal then this probably isn't your problem.)

For ctermbg and ctermfg you can enter color names, but I think there is only a fairly limited number:
 Black
DarkBlue
DarkGreen
DarkCyan
DarkRed
DarkMagenta
Brown, DarkYellow
LightGray, LightGrey, Gray, Grey
DarkGray, DarkGrey
Blue, LightBlue
Green, LightGreen
Cyan, LightCyan
Red, LightRed
Magenta, LightMagenta
Yellow, LightYellow
White

Otherwise you should be able to use a number from 0 to 255 in place of the color name.  Or this script gives rough idea, and lets you see how you could also set up to use more color names:
[Vim script with color settings](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Xterm256_color_names_for_console_Vim)

Also, there are a number of scripts that help you use or convert colorschemes written for gui for use with cterm.  E.g.,:

[Colorscheme support for cterm](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2682)

```
Does the overall settings for the terminal window have something to do with it?
```

Maybe, but I'm pretty sure a properly written Vim colorscheme will override any terminal settings you've made.  At least they do for me in Windows and on Ubuntu. . .

Comment: What does 'Normal' highlight mean? When I tpye "hi" in Ubuntu Shell, I get "cmd not known".

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `set termguicolors` to your ~/.vimrc

I tested `t_Co=256` and other options, but none worked, only `set termguicolors`

After this you can use the command `set bg=light` or `set bg=dark` to see witch one looks better (some vim color schemes accept both options).

Here is a list of terminals that are compatible with termguicolors: https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728#now-supporting-true-color

Comment: This worked for me. I had problems with vim on Ubuntu via SSH before.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and found out that the answer to this question is actually threefold, where fixing only two of the three isn't enough. You'll need to have:

1. 256-color support in your terminal - Putty with default settings does have this
2. Vim has to recognize that the terminal is 256-color capable: "set t_Co=256" in your .vimrc will do it
3. The color scheme needs to have support for color terminals with ctermbg and ctermfg attributes for highlights, not just the gui*-versions. http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2682 should be able to provide these automatically, and CSApprox I'm using most definitely does, but requires either +gui -compiled Vim or a recent enough Vim version (7.3 or newer).

The third one seems to be the most commonly missed requirement. I wrote a short piece on my own fumblings on this subject just this morning: http://codeandlife.com/2013/09/22/vim-colorschemes-with-putty-aka-gui-vs-xterm-color256/

Final gotcha that happened to me while trying different settings was that when the colors did work, only areas of screen with text had the proper background color. Re-checking Putty Terminal setting "Use background colour to erase screen" fixed that final issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

> Does the overall settings for the terminal window have something to do with it?

Yes, terminal parameters override vim parameters (at least in OSX and iTerm). For example, I have a following script in /Users/[username]/.bashrc

```
setBackground() {  
  osascript -e "tell application \"iTerm\"  
    set current_terminal to (current terminal)  
    tell current_terminal  
      set current_session to (current session)  
      tell current_session  
        set background color to $1  
      end tell  
    end tell  
  end tell"  
}  

vim() {
       (setBackground "{65025,65025,65025}" &)
       (exec vim $*)
}
```

The above remaps terminal vim command to execute a background color change before executing vim. Background color function is applescript (I copied the script from somewhere...).  It works for iTerm. I belive that you can adapt this to work with terminal (apple product + apple script -> should work).

br,
Juha

Answer (score 1):

Use this rule if you use **Vim** through **SSH**:

1. Add to your local `.bashrc`:

   ```
   export TERM=xterm-256color
   ```
2. Remove from `.bashrc` any `TERM` definitions.

If you use same `.bashrc` on both (local and remote), use temporary environment variable and **never** set `TERM` globally:

```
alias color-ssh='TERM=xterm-256color ssh user@host'
```

Comment: Please don't say *never* without at least *some* explanation. This is StackOverflow after all. People here are usually of the variety who like to know why and not just be scared to death.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me for switching backgrounds:

```
colorscheme hemisu
function! g:ToggleBackground()
  if &background != 'dark'
    set background=dark
  else
    set background=light
    colorscheme hemisu
  endif
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> <F3> :call g:ToggleBackground()<CR>
```

Also try setting light background to something like `ctermbg=231`, so that tmux handles it better.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue that the background color of indentation guides (nathanaelkane's vim-indent-guides) cannot be displayed in my Windows Cygwin's mintty terminal.

I solved the issue with a line `Term=xterm-256color` in ~/.minttyrc (equivalent to set via mintty's Options GUI: Terminal -> Type -> `xterm-256color`. This has the effect `export TERM=xterm-256color`. Without this, mintty default to TERM="xterm", which result in vim's `t_Co=8` (instead of `t_Co=256`) and cannot show some background color.

**Checklist:**

1. `echo $TERM` in bash should give `xterm-256color`.
2. in vim, `:set t_Co` should give `t_Co=256`.