# Why don't git colors show up in iTerm2

Tags: git, bash, iterm

So I have my gitconfig setup to do colors. In Terminal it works great, looks fine.

In iTerm2, however, the colors don't appear for my gitconfig at all unless I set the reverse property for git. Then they appear but who likes reversed colors anyways?

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You should check that iTerm is setting the TERM variable correctly. On my system, I see:

```
echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

And have working colours in git. This is set according to the 'Report Terminal Type' property in iTerm's preferences.

[image: here's a screenshot of iTerm 2's preferences]

You should also check the Colors tab, and ensure the contrast slider isn't all the way to the right.

Comment: Odd, I've tried that. I'm still seeing the escape codes from git log output:  ESC[33mcommit e56f9a33b767f551568ESC[m
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color

Comment: I'm guessing you have figured this out by now :) but in case others face the same problem and the above does not help: your problem is probably related to the pager (less), not to git. [A solution is available at the Unix&Linux StackExchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64932/40740).

Comment: +1 for "You should also check the Colors tab, and ensure the contrast slider isn't all the way to the right."

Answer (score 37):

In my case I had coloured output from other terminal applications in iTerm, just not git.
For anyone still looking to solve this, what did it for me was the solution from http://buildamodule.com/forum/post/iterm-git-ui-colors.

Modify your global git config as follows:

> git config --global color.ui true

Comment: my iTerm became absolutely pretty. :)

Comment: Oddly enough, `git log --color` worked, but for `color "diff"`, I needed this extra.

Comment: This got it working by prompting me to agree to Xcode License agreement again, I guess updating caused things to not work until re-agreeing.

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer to this via http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=1639 that works for me.

"The solution is to add this to your `~/.gitconfig` "

```
[core]
    pager = less -R
```

Answer (score 2):

For me this was not a git issue, but it was an iTerm2 issue on macOS. I ended up solving this by going to the iTerm2 Preferences > Window > Check the "Keep background colors opaque" checkbox and should now have no more pain or sorrows!
#RevDev

[image]