# Why is my vim theme not showing up in standard vim (not mvim)?

Tags: vim

I use the [made of code](https://gist.github.com/2c7582cb7d7a559c07b2) theme.  I was previously using macvim but switched to standard vim and am not seeing my normal syntax highlighting.  Is there a way to get it to work?

I've confirmed that :colorscheme is madeofcode, as well as echo $g:colors_name.  Thanks.

Comment: The colorscheme you link is a GUI only colorscheme.  The lack of `term` anywhere in the highlight definitions gives that away.

Comment: Is there a way I can change it to to a term theme?

Comment: You can use a plugin like CSApprox.vim to roughly convert it but the outcome isn't always that great.

Comment: Okay great.  I tried that but it's complaining about needing

Answer (score 1):

then it is probably showing, but you might

- not have defined `ctermfg`, `ctermbg` etc. (just `guifg`/`guibg`)
- the terminal might not be capable of displaying all the colours

See also

> **16. Color xterms**              `*xterm-color* *color-xterm*`
>
> ```
> Most color xterms have only eight colors.  If you don't get colors with the
> default setup, it should work with these lines in your .vimrc: >
>    :if &term =~ "xterm"
>    :  if has("terminfo")
>    :  set t_Co=8
>    :  set t_Sf=<Esc>[3%p1%dm
>    :  set t_Sb=<Esc>[4%p1%dm
>    :  else
>    :  set t_Co=8
>    :  set t_Sf=<Esc>[3%dm
>    :  set t_Sb=<Esc>[4%dm
>    :  endif
>    :endif
> < [<Esc> is a real escape, type CTRL-V <Esc>]
>
> You might want to change the first "if" to match the name of your terminal,
> e.g. "dtterm" instead of "xterm".
>
> Note: Do these settings BEFORE doing ":syntax on".  Otherwise the colors may
> be wrong.
> ```

Comment: That gave me some colors, but still a very small subset.  I'm not sure what my &term string would be (I'm running vim 7.3.3 on OS X Lion), so I just removed that condition.  The rest is giving me a subset of colors.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Or is this working correctly and the theme simply requires colors that are no longer available?

Answer (score 0):

Type `:echo &term` to know your `&term`, try `$ echo $TERM` in Terminal.app too to see if it's the same, just in case.

The `$TERM/&term` you need is `xterm-256color`.

You either set it from Terminal.app's preferences or from within Vim, like in sehe's answer, or as an argument when actually lauching Vim: `vim -T xterm-256color`.

Beware, though, trying to use a different terminal type than the one declared by Terminal.app will most definetly mess up with lots of things including colour and keymaps.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, wrote up answer below before I noticed in a comment that you are on OS x.  That's a different ball of wax, I think, I recall seeing fairly long SO thread on this issue for terminals on OS X. . . although this thread seems to indicate my solution works using iTerm:
[iterm vim colorscheme not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761770/iterm-vim-colorscheme-not-working)

---

This may also work, and is preferable to changing your terminal type.  Just put the line below in your vimrc before any `colorscheme` command.  Your xterm should support 256 colors, at least mine in Ubuntu does:

```
let &t_Co=256
```

That should fix the problem if the problem is xterm defaulting to too few colors, which you can confirm by doing `:echo &t_Co` in your terminal before applying fix above.  If it's currently a number less than 256 then it should help.

I think the help section on color-xterm quoted in another answer must be old.  My xterm on Ubuntu supports 256 as long as I do `set t_Co=256` or equivalent let statement above, and Wikipedia indicates that xterm supports 256 colors:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_terminal_emulators

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm